# Python PEP479 Change StopIteration handling inside generators

Tags: python, runtime-error, stopiteration

Could someone help me understand what PEP479 is about? I was reading the doc and couldn't get my head around it.

The abstract says:

> This PEP proposes a change to generators: when StopIteration is raised inside a generator, it is replaced it with RuntimeError. (More precisely, this happens when the exception is about to bubble out of the generator's stack frame.)

So for example, does a loop like so still work?

```
it = iter([1,2,3])
try:
    i = next(it)
    while True:
        i = next(it)
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Or does it mean that if I have a generator definition like so:

```
def gen():
    yield from range(5)
    raise StopIteration
```

the `StopIteration` is going to be replaced with `RuntimeError`?

I would really appreciate if someone could shed some light on this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your first loop should still work -- `StopIteration` will still be raised when a generator is exhausted.

The difference is that there *was* ambiguity when a `StopIteration` was raised in a generator.  Did it get raised (implicitly) because the generator ran out of things to yield -- Or did it get raised because a delegate generator ran out of things to yield (maybe due to a `next` call) and the exception wasn't handled properly?  PEP-0479 tries to address that ambiguity.  Now if you get a `StopIteration`, it means that the generator you are working with ran out items to yield.  Said another way, it means that a delegate generator *didn't* get mis-handled when running out of items.

To support this change, your generator should `return` instead of raising `StopIteration` explicitly.

```
def gen():
    yield from range(5)
    return
```

---

Here's what happens if you try it with the `StopIteration` and `generator_stop` enabled (which will become the default when python3.7 comes around):

```
>>> from __future__ import generator_stop
>>> def gen():
...     yield from range(5)
...     raise StopIteration
... 
>>> list(gen())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in gen
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

Comment: I see. I stumbled upon this as I was reading about `StopAsyncIteration`. It all makes sense now. Many thanks.