# Exception broadcasting with generator expressions (Python)

Tags: python, exception, generator-expression

I came across the following behaviour. Having used a block of code with the following structure,

```
try:
    tup = tuple(<some_expression> for <_> in <iterator>)
except <SomeException>:
    pass
```

when `SomeException` was raised during the generation of the tuple (within the generator expression), the `try`-`except` block didn't handle it and instead the whole program halted. Why is that so? And is there a way to ensure exceptions encountered in genexpr. are "broadcasted" to the outer scope?

### Concrete example

`test.py`:

```
def input_generator():
    try:
        while True:
            for token in input().split():
                yield token
    except EOFError:
        pass


pyIn = input_generator()


def tuple_gen(n: int):
    try:
        while True:
            yield tuple(next(pyIn) for _ in range(n))
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    except ValueError:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for a, b in tuple_gen(2):
        print(a, b)
```

Consider iterating over an instance of the `tuple_gen` generator, with an empty file as input (as `stdin`). Upon encountering EOF, the `pyIn` generator terminates and thus `next(pyIn)` raises `StopIteration`, but instead of being caught by the `except` block, the program halts.

For example, saving an empty `test.txt` file (just an empty line) and running this on the (Windows) console

```
python test.py < test.txt
```

results in the following Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <genexpr>
    yield tuple(next(pyIn) for _ in range(n))
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 24, in <module>
    for a, b in tuple_gen(2):
  File "test.py", line 16, in tuple_gen
    yield tuple(next(pyIn) for _ in range(n))
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

### Update

As pointed out in the comments by timgeb, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37707187/python-pep479-change-stopiteration-handling-inside-generators) question explains the issue at hand.

Comment: Could you make your concrete example... concreter? Such that it is runnable and shows the behavior you are trying to showcase here.

Comment: @timgeb Yes, I should have done that before. Is the example provided sufficient?

Comment: Ah. You are not catching the `RuntimeError`.

Comment: @timgeb Oh, I see. But why does `StopIteration` get "transformed" into a generic `RuntimeError`?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37707187/python-pep479-change-stopiteration-handling-inside-generators) should solve the issue.